# Alternative of Infragistics JS for displaying graphs in the Cordova/Phonegap application

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, infragistics

I am using infragistics.core & infragistics.dv js files in my Cordova/Phonegap application for displaying some chart/graph views. I Couldn't find out any MIT license for using it for commercial purpose. So I want to use some free library as I don't want to create any licensing issue. Which is the best alternative free library to replace Infragistics? I am using jQuery Mobile framework for the screen designs. So the graph library should be compatible with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Chartjs, flotchart,..

Answer (score 0):

Chartist 
http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

ChartJS
http://www.chartjs.org/

Flot
http://www.flotcharts.org/

I love amCharts http://www.amcharts.com/ free version can be used but put a link on the chart

Answer (score 0):

A great, and very popular, solution is [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) that create very nice svg/css charts. I've used it in a commercial cordova project without legal or integration problems.

Here you can find examples for some [basic charts](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery#basic-charts).

It's released under the [BSD 3-Clause license](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause) that allows redistribution: but read the [D3.js license file for more information](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/LICENSE) or search in stackoverflow for additional details.